# Encrypt ip addresses

Tags: algorithm

I need to encrypt ip adresses. Example this is my ip adress:78.172.16.193 I need to convert this adress to 6 character word. It may contain integer or string. Also It should be decryptable for me.

How can I do this? I am waiting your suggestions.

I will be using this in NodeJS. I don't want code, I want an algorithm.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem. Show us something that you've tried. Also, this is a very broad question so you might not get the answer you're looking for, if you get one at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO! From all the question we get in lately it may look you can just put your requirements in a question and get an answer, but actually you would need to show effort. Show us where you are stuck? Why your solution didn't work. What the result was. What the expected result is.

Comment: You really need to give us more to go on here. What do you know about encryption? Do you know how to program? Is there a language you will use? You could simply convert the four octets into characters. That's a form of encryption. Search for encryption algorithms on your favorite search engine. That would be a good place to start.

Comment: This is not a homework.I know the SO but this is a algorithm question.I will use it in nodejs.I don't want a code from you I just need an algorithm.

Comment: Why 6 chars? That seems like a pretty arbitrary number.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu How many chars you need ?

Comment: I don't know what you plan on using this for, but one way you could do it is casting them all to a character and adding two random characters to the end. Then, you could reconvert the first four characters to four separate integers and ignore the last two.

Comment: Well, as already mentioned, 4 chars would be enough to obfuscate or encrypt the data. Actually, an IP address already is 4 chars long.

Comment: @Etienne Maheu Only if you have 256 characters, but the way I understood it is only [a-z][A-Z][0-9] are allowed.

Comment: @jgritty All characters are allowed.Just I need a obfuscated ip adress with 6 chars.

Comment: Well if that's what you need, you could use Base64? It seems like a good pick for your case and it would be enough to fit in the entire ip address space in 5 chars.

Comment: Base64 is not returning 6 chars ?

Comment: Sorry, the 5 was a typo. Base64 is an algorithm that allows only 64 possible values out of the 256 possible to store data inside a character in a string. Actually, you need at least 6 x 64 values (~68 billion) to express 4 x 256 values (~4 billion). 5 Base64 characters would only provide around 1 billion possibilities so Base64 would fit your case perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Base64. It is widely used and probably already supported on your target framework. Just as base 10 allows only 10 possible glyphs within a character, base 64 allows 64 glyphs per characters. To express a 32 bit number such an an IP address, you would need at a base 64 number that has at least 6 values.

```
256 x 256 x 256 x 256        => ~4 billion
64 x 64 x 64 x 64 x 64       => ~1 billion  : 5 is not enough so lets use 6
64 x 64 x 64 x 64 x 64 x 64  => ~69 billion : it fits and there is still some headroom
```

This solution fits your 6 characters requirement. If you drop that requirement though, you could simply xor the original value using a 32 bit symmetrical key. This is crude, but strong enough to obfuscate the IP address if there isn't any patterns in the data you are transferring (like if the IP always starts with 192.168). It is also susceptible to all zeros or all ones attacks.

```
IP address    => 1100 0000 1010 1000 0000 0000 0000 0001 <= 192.168.0.1
symmetric key => 1011 1101 0101 1010 1011 1101 0101 1010 <= 189.90.189.90
xor result    => 0111 1101 1111 0010 1011 1101 0101 1011 <= 125.242.189.91
```

If you simply xor the address again with the same key, you will end up with the original address again. As you can see, the third element leaks the key because xor simply flips the bits.

Answer (score 0):

Integer or string means you have 26 + 26 + 10 chars to choose from.  62 choices.  This maps to 6^62 available strings.

There are 256^4 ip addresses to represent.

This should be fairly trivial to come up with some mapping.

You won't be able to easily specify the decimals, as you can't waste 3 chars for them, and still be able to squeeze the 4 nodes into 3 characters.  So, you'll definitely need to combine the IP into a single block, which you seem to have already done, without showing work.